# Cannot read property socket of Undefined TypeError in chrome.sockets API

Tags: javascript, sockets, google-chrome

I'm programming a chrome JS extensions that uses sockets to communicate with a Java server.
When I use the following line :

```
var socket = chrome.socket || chrome.experimental.socket;
socket.create('tcp',{},function(createInfo) {
```

I get the

```
Error in event handler for 'tabs.onUpdated': Cannot read property 'socket' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'socket' of undefined
```

error (the JS code is in a tabs.onUpdated function).

My manifest file is :

```
{
      "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "MitM Phishing Detector",
  "description": "This extension protects your browser against phishing attacks based on MitM attacks",
  "version": "1.0",

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["notify.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "bluetooth_device.png",
    "default_popup": "choose_device.html"
  },

  "permissions": [
      "tabs", 
      "http://*/*", 
      "background", 
      {"socket": 
       [ "tcp-connect:127.0.0.1:8081" ] 
      },
      "notifications"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the canary/experimental build of Chrome you should be able to do

```
chrome.experimental.socket.create('tcp', ...)
```

to open a TCP socket. But just calling `socket.create` won't work.

Remember that this will probably only ever work on chrome... WebSockets are a much more portable solution.

To set socket properly I think that this should work (havn't tested it):

```
var socket = chrome.socket;
if (unfefined !== chrome.experimental.socket)
  socket = chrome.experimental.socket;
if (undefined === chrome.socket)
  throw "Socket unavailable"
```

Comment: but since I use var socket = chrome.experimental.socket, it should work right?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. `undefined` is still a value - so it could be assigned undefined in the `||` statement. Added possible "better" way to do it.